# Битрикс. Интеграция 1С

Tags: битрикс, 1с

[image]

Установлен модуль обмена с корпоративным порталом. При попытке добавления сотрудника появляется такая ошибка. Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: Вы уверены, что версия модуля подходит под версию вашей конфигурации?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка означает, что тип данных, который вы пытаетесь зарегистрировать для обмена, не предусмотрен в плане обмена. Скорее всего @Yura Ivanov прав, и версия модуля не подходит.
Либо были какие-то ручные изменения в 1с.